# Having trouble with button events (click triggers) in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, shopify, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

So I have an add to cart button on my Shopify store that I want a tag to fire off in Google Tag Manager at a 5-second delay after being clicked.

The buttons class is: `btn product-form__cart-submit`

Here is the button:

```
<button type="submit" name="add" aria-label="Add to cart" class="btn product-form__cart-submit" aria-haspopup="dialog" data-add-to-cart="">
```

I have tried the following:

click classes contains/equals/matches css selector, etc. but nothing works. What is the proper way to format this tag so that every time the button is clicked that it will fire off?

Answer (score 0):

Confirming you've enabled the built-in variable "Click Element".

In your Trigger Condition did you append the * so your condition would be captured for all of the nested elements within the button? `btn product-form__cart-submit *`